# Repeated columns not displayed in SSRS report

Tags: reporting-services, ssrs-2008, ssrs-2008-r2

I am working on a SSRS report. I am getting the data from a stored proc. The table kind of looks like this

[image]

There are other columns too, but I am having problem with this particular columns, because of the repeated values among the columns and also repeated values in the columns itself. But each and every row is different from the other in atleast one column value.

My table has a lot of columns so I cannot display them all horizontally, like  a normal report. So I made the report like

[image]

Company as a Parent group.

My problem is, when i group the table on Company, it is taking the first value of the Number column (when the Number column is repeated) for example in the above table 123 is repeated three times in line, in this case the report is displaying only the Number and details for the following row in my report. It is not displaying the following 123 values which are together.

Note: i also applied the page break to the group.

I don't think my approach is correct, but i couldn't find any other better approach.

Please anyone help me with this. thank you guys.

Comment: "because of the repeated values among the columns". It sounds like you have a join issue. Have you established that the SQL you are using to populate the report is correct? Get your SQL right and you won't have to fiddle about in SSRS

Comment: I am sure that my query is correct. But I will check it again and see if that helps me.
But to be clear, The values are repeating among the columns but for the over all rows and columns they are distinct. they differ in any one of the existing column values

Comment: I don't quite understand your explanation of the repeating issue. But if you want _one_ customer heading with many child records you need to add some kind of detail group. So in the tablix (?) right click on the row and you'll see _Insert Row_, _Inside Group Below_. You'll need to experiment with that.

Comment: The repeating issue is quite similar with my example table. Each row is unique (Distinct). Lets say Number, Name, Company, Amount and Customer is same for two rows then the date is different for those two. If the Number, Company, Amount, Customer and Date is same, it differs with the column Name. Kind of like that. Hope it is understandable. For my requirement, I have to display corresponding details based on the Name parameter.

Comment: What does the date signify? if you have two, which one do you want to show? the largest? smallest? most recent record? I don't understand 'differs with the column name'. What do you mean by that?

Comment: Every record should be displayed. 'differs with the column name' means a column called 'Name'. I am sorry I should have been more specific when i typed it.  Anyways, I figured it out. Thank you for your time :)

Comment: Glad you figured it :)

Comment: If you figured it out please add the answer to this question otherwise other people with the same problem in the future wrong know what to do